# Array and object delete in MQL4 indicator

Tags: arrays, mql4, metatrader4, technical-indicator

I'm trying to create an indicator that identifies some price zones that interest me. I was able to create it perfectly and the logic works, the only problem is that I would like to eliminate the price zones that are invalidated (ie exceeded) but it is proving very difficult for me. I've tried saving the values of the object in an array, and then comparing them to the prices, but no luck.

Now I've tried another approach, saving the name in the array, then fetching the price with Objectget. With a comment I can see that the name is saved in the array, but not working :(

This is the code I use in a while loop inside oncalculate to create the zones and save the name :

```
  if (isCandleSequenceLong)
        {
        string LongName = "Bullish" + DoubleToString (Low[i + 2 ], 0 );
        ObjectCreate (LongName, OBJ_RECTANGLE , 0 , Time[i + 3 ], High[i + 2 ], EMPTY_VALUE , Low[i + 2 ]);
        ObjectSet(LongName, OBJPROP_COLOR , Lime);
        if (!FillZone)
        ObjectSet(LongName, OBJPROP_BACK , false );
        rectangleLongName[i] = LongName;
        isCandleSequenceLong  = false ;
        }

       if (isCandleSequenceShort)
        {
        string ShortName = "Bearish" + DoubleToString (High[i + 2 ], 0 );
        ObjectCreate (ShortName, OBJ_RECTANGLE , 0 , Time[i + 3 ], High[i + 2 ], EMPTY_VALUE , Low[i + 2 ]);
        ObjectSet(ShortName, OBJPROP_COLOR , Red);
        if (!FillZone)
        ObjectSet(ShortName, OBJPROP_BACK , false );
        rectangleShortName[i] = ShortName;
        isCandleSequenceShort = false ;
        }
```

And this is the function that should eliminate them  :

```
void DeleteBrokeZone()
{
     for ( int j = 0 ; j < ObjectsTotal ()- 1 ; j++)
    {
     double LongPrice = ObjectGet(rectangleLongName[j],OBJPROP_PRICE2);
     double ShortPrice= ObjectGet(rectangleShortName[j],OBJPROP_PRICE1);
     Comment (LongPrice);
             if (Close[j + 1 ] > LongPrice && Close[j] < LongPrice )
            {
                 if (!ObjectDelete (rectangleLongName[j])) Print ( "Error:" + rectangleLongName[j]);
            }
             if (Close[j + 1 ]  < ShortPrice && Close[j]  > ShortPrice)
            {
                 if (!ObjectDelete (rectangleShortName[j])) Print ( "Error:" + rectangleShortName[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to whoever can help me!

Comment: You need to post your full code in order to receive help. At a brief glance, you are confusing your `j` variable in the `DeleteBrokeZone` function. `j` is the number of objects, but you are also using `j` to find `Close` prices which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Paul! is that honestly I would not post the design logic of the areas, as the indicator must not be distributed on the internet. Why the incorrect use of the j? j is declared as 0 and incremented with each turn of the for loop, up to the number of objects. So the code should check for close[1], close[2] etc..

I modified the function and now I get some result, but I still can't delete all zones, only some are deleted correctly, older ones don't. I post the code

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isCandleSequenceLong)
       {
        static int longcounter  = 1000;
        string LongName = "Bullish" + IntegerToString(longcounter, 0);
        ObjectCreate(LongName, OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, Time[i + 3 ], High[i + 2 ], EMPTY_VALUE, Low[i + 2 ]);
        ObjectSet(LongName, OBJPROP_COLOR, Lime);
        if(!FillZone)
           ObjectSet(LongName, OBJPROP_BACK, false);
        rectangleLongName[longArrayCounter] = LongName;
        isCandleSequenceLong  = false ;
        longcounter++;
        longArrayCounter++;
       }

     if(isCandleSequenceShort)
       {
        static int shortcounter = 1000;
        string ShortName = "Bearish" + IntegerToString(shortcounter, 0);
        ObjectCreate(ShortName, OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, Time[i + 3 ], High[i + 2 ], EMPTY_VALUE, Low[i + 2 ]);
        ObjectSet(ShortName, OBJPROP_COLOR, Red);
        if(!FillZone)
           ObjectSet(ShortName, OBJPROP_BACK, false);
        rectangleShortName[shortArrayCounter] = ShortName;
        isCandleSequenceShort = false ;
        shortcounter++;
        shortArrayCounter++;
       }

void DeleteBrokeZone()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize(rectangleLongName); i++)
    {
        if (StringLen(rectangleLongName[i]) > 0)
        {
            if (ObjectFind(NULL, rectangleLongName[i]) != -1)
            {
                price1 = ObjectGetDouble(0, rectangleLongName[i], OBJPROP_PRICE1);
                price2 = ObjectGetDouble(0, rectangleLongName[i], OBJPROP_PRICE2);

                if (Close[i] < price2)
                {
                    if (!ObjectDelete(0, rectangleLongName[i])) {
                        Print("Error deleting Long object: " + rectangleLongName[i]);
                        }
                    else 
                        Print("Deleted Long object: " + rectangleLongName[i]);
                    rectangleLongName[i] = ""; 
                    RefreshRates();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < ArraySize(rectangleShortName); x++)
    {
        if (StringLen(rectangleShortName[x]) > 0)
        {
            if (ObjectFind(NULL, rectangleShortName[x]) != -1)
            {
                price1 = ObjectGetDouble(0, rectangleShortName[x], OBJPROP_PRICE1);
                price2 = ObjectGetDouble(0, rectangleShortName[x], OBJPROP_PRICE2);

                if (Close[x] > price1)
                {
                    if (!ObjectDelete(0, rectangleShortName[x])) {
                        Print("Error deleting Short object: " + rectangleShortName[x]);
                        }
                    else
                        Print("Deleted Short object: " + rectangleShortName[x]);
                    rectangleShortName[x] = ""; 
                    RefreshRates();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes I can get it to delete some invalid zones, but unfortunately not all. Some remain designed even if surpassed by the price

Comment: You are still not using the variables correctly. You are using `i` and `x` to iterate through the your arrays. These index number therefore relate to the array you are working with. You are then using that index number to reference the `Close` price. The `Close[]` variable needs a candle reference, `0` being the current candle and so on. Therefore using the `i` and `x` index with the close price makes no sense as the `Close` prices you receive will not be related to the the object you are referencing. Please read the [Documentation](https://docs.mql4.com/predefined/close)

Comment: Also, you should not add additional code an an answer, just edit your original question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).